# JRE system library not found exception in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

Dear All, I am eclipse3.1 IDE for java under fedora 8 environment. I installed fresh copy of eclipse and trying to run a program,it shows JRE system library not found exception popup. I added this library manually by BuildPath-----> Add external library but still i am getting that popup. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Which type program do you run? Java application or eclipse configuration?

Comment: Both the below answers solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to **Window** - **Preference** - **Java** - **Installed JREs** page to specify the location of your jre or JDK.

Comment: Thanks Kane again checked Window - Preference - Java - Installed JREs->the path that referring was not correct.Now its works Fine.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Project > Properties >Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Next > Just Finish** This is work for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but maybe try checking in Java Build Path that your lib appears in the Libraries tab and that in "Order and Export" tab it is checked

otherwise have you tried refreshing cleaning and rebuilding?(sometimes eclipse is a bit slow in detecting changes

final check that the path of the library is the good one (it happened when I committed a project to the svn and used it on a different computer, everything was there but since the computers had different names (C:\jason... and C:\jasonlaptop...) it wasn't working.

let me know if it changed anything

Comment: Thanks a lot the path that referring was not correct.Now its works Fine.

Comment: Great glad it worked out and good luck with your project ^^, don't forget to mark the answer so that people know that your problem is solved and what solved it.